# Barra de progreso en archivo .bat

Tags: windows, cmd, batch, powershell

Estoy creando un archivo `.bat` para realizar copias de seguridad con `Robocopy`. Ha ese fichero `.bat` le he añadido comandos para crear una barra de progreso del mismo archivo `.bat`. Mi problema es que con mi código, lo que hace el archivo es realizar el comando de Robocopy y luego ejecutar la barra de progreso.

Mi idea es que no se vea la ejecución del `Robocopy` y solo salga la barra de progreso. ¿Alguna ayuda?

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

robocopy "C:\Usuario\Carpeta1" "C:\Usuario\Carpeta2" /e /r:1 /w:1 /mir

Echo.Realizando copia de seguridad, espera....
Call :BarraDeCarga
Pause
Exit

:BarraDeCarga
Echo.
Echo. Loading...
Echo.
Set "bar="
Set "percent=0"
Set "count=0"
For /L %%I In (1,1,20) Do (Set "bar=!bar!±")
:Loop
Set /P "= %bar:~0,20% %percent%%%"<Nul
Set "asdf=%Random:~0,1%"
If %asdf% GEQ 8 (
    Set /A "asdf=asdf-4"
)
Ping -n %asdf:~0,1% -w %asdf:~0,1% LocalHost>nul
For /L %%I In (1,1,26) Do Set /p "="<Nul
Set "bar=Û%bar%"
Set /a "count+=1"
Set /a "percent+=5"
If %count% LEQ 20 Goto:Loop
Echo.
Echo.
Echo. Done.
Goto :Eof
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Realmente con un.bat no podras lograr una barra de progreso que capture realmente lo que seria el progreso de la copia de archivos con Robocopy. Tu script en este caso solo ejecuta una rutina de progreso indistintamente si los archivos han sido copiados en su totalidad o no.

Te propongo utilizar una funcion hecha en PowerShell que si puede medir el progreso real de una copia de archivos con Robocopy. La he utilizado y funciona a la perfeccion.

Ahora bien entremos en detalle. La funcion es llamada `Copy-WithProgress`. Para implementar y utilizar esta funcion solo consta de dos pasos:

**1. Agregar la funcion a PowerShell pegando el codigo de la funcion en la consola de PowerShell, enter y listo**

**2. Llamar a la funcion pasandole dos parametros que son el directorio origen y el directorio destino de la copia**, seria de esta forma:

```
 Copy-WithProgress -Source 'Dir_Origen' -Destination 'Dir_Destino';
```

Esta es una imagen de como funciona, aqui estoy copiando un directorio de musica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui te doy algunos detalles de la funcion:

La función se divide en regiones:

- Parámetros comunes de robocopy
- Puesta en escena (donde se calcula el tamaño del trabajo de robocopy)
- Copia (donde se inicia el trabajo de robocopy)
- Barra de progreso (donde se supervisa el progreso de la robocopia)
- Salida de función (donde se generan algunas estadísticas útiles, para
  usar en el resto de su script)

Hay varios parámetros en la función.

- Fuente : el directorio fuente
- Destino : el directorio de destino
- Brecha : La "brecha entre paquetes" en milisegundos compatible con
  robocopy, que ralentiza artificialmente la copia, para la prueba)
- ReportGap : el intervalo (en milisegundos) para verificar el progreso
  de la robocopy

Para crear la funcion solo debes abrir la consola de PowerShell y pegar este codigo:

```
function Copy-WithProgress {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param (
                [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
                [string] $Source
            , [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
                [string] $Destination
            , [int] $Gap = 200
            , [int] $ReportGap = 2000
        )
        # Define regular expression that will gather number of bytes copied
        $RegexBytes = '(?<=\s+)\d+(?=\s+)';

        #region Robocopy params
        # MIR = Mirror mode
        # NP  = Don't show progress percentage in log
        # NC  = Don't log file classes (existing, new file, etc.)
        # BYTES = Show file sizes in bytes
        # NJH = Do not display robocopy job header (JH)
        # NJS = Do not display robocopy job summary (JS)
        # TEE = Display log in stdout AND in target log file
        $CommonRobocopyParams = '/MIR /NP /NDL /NC /BYTES /NJH /NJS';
        #endregion Robocopy params

        #region Robocopy Staging
        Write-Verbose -Message 'Analyzing robocopy job ...';
        $StagingLogPath = '{0}\temp\{1} robocopy staging.log' -f $env:windir, (Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss');

        $StagingArgumentList = '"{0}" "{1}" /LOG:"{2}" /L {3}' -f $Source, $Destination, $StagingLogPath, $CommonRobocopyParams;
        Write-Verbose -Message ('Staging arguments: {0}' -f $StagingArgumentList);
        Start-Process -Wait -FilePath robocopy.exe -ArgumentList $StagingArgumentList -NoNewWindow;
        # Get the total number of files that will be copied
        $StagingContent = Get-Content -Path $StagingLogPath;
        $TotalFileCount = $StagingContent.Count - 1;

        # Get the total number of bytes to be copied
        [RegEx]::Matches(($StagingContent -join "`n"), $RegexBytes) | % { $BytesTotal = 0; } { $BytesTotal += $_.Value; };
        Write-Verbose -Message ('Total bytes to be copied: {0}' -f $BytesTotal);
        #endregion Robocopy Staging

        #region Start Robocopy
        # Begin the robocopy process
        $RobocopyLogPath = '{0}\temp\{1} robocopy.log' -f $env:windir, (Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss');
        $ArgumentList = '"{0}" "{1}" /LOG:"{2}" /ipg:{3} {4}' -f $Source, $Destination, $RobocopyLogPath, $Gap, $CommonRobocopyParams;
        Write-Verbose -Message ('Beginning the robocopy process with arguments: {0}' -f $ArgumentList);
        $Robocopy = Start-Process -FilePath robocopy.exe -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -Verbose -PassThru -NoNewWindow;
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100;
        #endregion Start Robocopy

        #region Progress bar loop
        while (!$Robocopy.HasExited) {
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $ReportGap;
            $BytesCopied = 0;
            $LogContent = Get-Content -Path $RobocopyLogPath;
            $BytesCopied = [Regex]::Matches($LogContent, $RegexBytes) | ForEach-Object -Process { $BytesCopied += $_.Value; } -End { $BytesCopied; };
            $CopiedFileCount = $LogContent.Count - 1;
            Write-Verbose -Message ('Bytes copied: {0}' -f $BytesCopied);
            Write-Verbose -Message ('Files copied: {0}' -f $LogContent.Count);
            $Percentage = 0;
            if ($BytesCopied -gt 0) {
               $Percentage = (($BytesCopied/$BytesTotal)*100)
            }
            Write-Progress -Activity Robocopy -Status ("Copied {0} of {1} files; Copied {2} of {3} bytes" -f $CopiedFileCount, $TotalFileCount, $BytesCopied, $BytesTotal) -PercentComplete $Percentage
        }
        #endregion Progress loop

        #region Function output
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            BytesCopied = $BytesCopied;
            FilesCopied = $CopiedFileCount;
        };
        #endregion Function output
    }
```

Comment: @Maginon si la respuesta a tu pregunta fue de tu utilidad puedes aceptarla, en este [Enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) te muestran como hacerlo y al mismo tiempo ganas +2 de reputacion. Saludos!